# Trouble with overriding properties in Spring-batch

Tags: spring

We are using Spring 4.3.9 with Spring Batch 3.   We are using maven to copy resources with filtering to merge profile-based properties into the configs at build time.  I want to allow my DevOps engineers to override property file settings (db passwords) at deployment time to the environment specific property, so I've setup things as shown below, but the overrides don't work:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyOverrideConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:bluecost-OVERRIDE.properties" />
</bean> 

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${datasource.database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${datasource.database.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${datasource.database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${datasource.database.password}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${datasource.maxPoolSize}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${datasource.minPoolSize}" />
</bean>
```

The property file that maven merges with all default values looks like this:

```
datasource.database.driverClassName=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
datasource.database.url=jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/bluecost
datasource.database.username=not-real-id
datasource.database.password=not-real-pwd
datasource.maxPoolSize=50
datasource.minPoolSize=10
```

And finally, my bluecost-OVERRIDE.properties file has the correct values for just the username and password, configured like this:

```
# Overriding values for the datasource property values
datasource.database.username=db2inst
datasource.database.password=db2inst1
```

The override file is surely in the classpath (it wouldn't start without finding it anyway).  It's throwing errors at runtime because of the invalid (default) userid/pwd.

Why doesn't it override the userid/pwd like I want it to?

Comment: Because that isn't how the `PropertyOverrideConfigurer` works. It works by looking at the beans and property names and checks if it can find an override. So in your case it would check for `dataSource.user` (for instance). What you want it to load both files (the latter optionally) in your `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and let that take care of it.

Comment: I tried changing the override property values to this:
datasource.user=db2inst
datasource.password=db2inst1
It didn't work either.  What I want is to have the default values to come from the config.properties that maven merges into the context files at build time.   I then want the bluecost-OVERRIDE.properties file to be an optional file that Spring looks for and if it finds it, it will override the values in the respective beans.

Comment: I tried override file with dataSource.user and dataSource.password - didn't work either

Comment: Don't do it like that. You don't want to use placeholders and maven like that. That would also mean you rebuild your project for each environment (local, test, acceptance, production) and that is something you don't want to do. You are basically going live without proper testing. Just use the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` which loads the default configuration and the optional configuration file and use that. Don't use maven with resource filtering etc. for that.

Comment: Once is enough, assuming that all those xml files make up the same `ApplicationContext`.